# twitter like list view

Tags: android, listview, twitter, android-listview

I am making an app that has a listview(big deal :P), and I want to have it a ui like that of twitter's feeds.

Now I have achieved quite the same result, but the difference is that, if u scroll in the twitter app, the scrollbar appears to the right of the screen, however, for my app, it appears in the list view.

Please see the screenshots to see what i mean

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14534468/I.png

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14534468/twitter.png

here is the xml code i am using.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:divider="#d1d1d1"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

where rounded is

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Any ideas how can I achieve the same?

Comment: Seems like it's just a matter of adding a bit of padding on the right. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give your Items the margin, not the ListView - or maybe it works with a padding given to the ListView.

Comment: Really? How about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarStyle ?

Comment: @Amit where did u add it (framelayout(framelayout(listview))), i can put it where i want "outsideOverlay" always displays the Scrollbar inside.